# Branch.io deeplink not working in my browser

Tags: javascript, android, branch.io

I created the link in the branch.io dashboard. https://app.zebpay.com/zFAzt88rcT but the link is not working when i opened it in the browser.

I also tried the journey mobile banners they also not changing the button text to the open when I already installed the app on my mobile.

I already added the web sdk code on my website.

Answer (score 1):

The link does not seem to be a valid branch custom link. Please contact integrations@branch.io to troubleshoot this domain and link.

Comment: i didn't get you not valid custom link means, can you please explain why?

Comment: For a subdomain to work with branch as a custom sub domain the C Name should be owned by Branch. I don't see it to be the case with app.zebpay.com. How did you generate this link ?

Comment: i created the new link in branch dashboard